# multipart/x-mixed-replace - MJPG video stream does not close in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, ffmpeg

I'm using Node.js and React.
In React I have a simple component that is displayed on the screen when a button is clicked. The component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'

const Image = () => {
  return <img src="/api/mjpgStream/stream01"></img>;
}
```

Webpack redirects my requests (api=localhost:3456/mjpgStream/stream0).
In node I created an express server that when receiving the GET continuously sends JPEG images with multipart/x-mixed-replace. Below is the code:

```
const cb: RequestHandler = (req, res) => {
  const url = req.url.toString().slice(1);
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary='stream'",
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    Expires: "Fri, 27 May 1977 00:00:00 GMT",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
    Pragma: "no-cache",
  });
  let sub = PubSub.subscribe(url, function (msg: any, data: any) {
    res.write("--stream\r\n");
    res.write("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n");
    res.write("Content-Length: " + data.length + "\r\n");
    res.write("\r\n");
    res.write(data, "binary");
    res.write("\r\n");
  });

  req.on("close", () => {
    PubSub.unsubscribe(sub);
    res.end();
  });

  res.on("error", function (err) {
    console.error("Error in response:", err);
  });
};

router.get(/\/[a-z,0-9]*/, cb);
```

The video stream is published in the topic with PubSub and is correctly displayed in the Image component.
The problem is that when I click the button to close the Image component from the web page, the close event is not captured on the express server side and the mjpg flow continues to exist. I can't understand why.